# Postgresql substract two columns and substract remainder from next row

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have a test CTE as follows:

```sql
with test_cte (month, company, probability, expected, actual) as (values
('2024-03','CompA',100,4,13),
('2024-03','CompA',80,7,13),
('2024-03','CompA',50,7,13)
)
select * from test_cte
```

What I would like to do is add a final column called 'expected_revised' which would be 'expected' reduced by the amount in 'actual' (which itself gets depleted row after row).

*Edit: additionnally, the decrease in the 'actual' value must cease upon reaching 0, indicating full utilization against the expected value.*

The partition should be:

```sql
partition by month, company order by probability DESC
```

The column 'expected-revised' should return:

```
0 (greatest(0,4-13))
0 (greatest(0,7-(13-4)))
5 (greatest(0,7-(13-4-7)))
```

Any thoughts? I feel i should use a window function for this but can't figure out how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
0 (greatest(0,4-13)) => 4 - 13
0 (greatest(0,7-(13-4))) => 7+4 - 13
5 (greatest(0,7-(13-4-7))) => 7+4+7 - 13
```

You need to substract actual value from the running total of the expected values :

```
WITH test_cte (month, company, probability, expected, actual) AS (VALUES
    ('2024-03', 'CompA', 100, 4, 13),
    ('2024-03', 'CompA', 80, 7, 13),
    ('2024-03', 'CompA', 50, 7, 13)
)
SELECT *,
        GREATEST(0, SUM(expected) OVER (PARTITION BY month, company ORDER BY probability DESC) - actual) AS expected_revised
FROM test_cte;
```

Results :

```
month   company probability expected    actual  expected_revised
2024-03 CompA   100         4           13      0
2024-03 CompA   80          7           13      0
2024-03 CompA   50          7           13      5
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/wcogQwKP)

---

A recent comment introduces a new condition stating that the decrease in the *actual* value must cease upon reaching 0, indicating full utilization against the *expected* value.

```
WITH test_cte (month, company, probability, expected, actual) AS (
  VALUES
    ('2024-03', 'CompA', 100, 4, 10),
    ('2024-03', 'CompA', 80, 7, 10),
    ('2024-03', 'CompA', 50, 7, 10)
),
test_cte2 as (
  SELECT *,
    SUM(expected) OVER (PARTITION BY month, company ORDER BY probability DESC) as running_expected
  FROM test_cte
)
SELECT month, company, probability, expected, actual,
       CASE
         WHEN LAG(running_expected) OVER (PARTITION BY month, company ORDER BY probability DESC) > actual THEN expected
         ELSE GREATEST(0, running_expected - actual)
       END AS expected_revised
FROM test_cte2
```

Comment: Once we get into negative territory for the remainder before the last row, this does not seem to work anymore. For example, if you replace 13 by 10 in my test_cte, the last row shows 8 instead of 7. Any idea how to control for this?

Comment: why it should be 7 instead of 8 ?  7-(10-4-7) = 8 not 7, can you explain your logic

Comment: Sorry that was not clear in the original message indeed. The 'depletion' of the actual figure has to stop when we get to 0 (<=> when it has been fully used up against the expected figure). Does that make sense?
When fully used up in previous rows, we just use the expected figure.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to cover the case i mentioned above in the comments:

```
WITH test_cte (month, company, probability, expected, actual) AS (VALUES

('2024-03', 'CompA', 100, 4, 10),

('2024-03', 'CompA', 80, 7, 10),

('2024-03', 'CompA', 50, 7, 10)

), test_cte2 as (

SELECT *,

SUM(expected) OVER (PARTITION BY month, company ORDER BY probability DESC) as col_2_check,

GREATEST(0, SUM(expected) OVER (PARTITION BY month, company ORDER BY probability DESC) - actual) AS expected_revised

FROM test_cte

)

select

*,

case

when lag(col_2_check,1) over (PARTITION BY month, company ORDER BY probability desc) > actual then expected

else expected_revised

end as expected_revised_final

from test_cte2
```

Not sure if there is a better way to handle this.

Comment: The expected running total does not need to be calculated twice! please check my recent [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77805418/4286884)

Comment: You are correct, the above is simpler and works. I will also amend my original post to precise that new condition. Thanks for your help again!